# Android NumberPicker getValue() return wrong result

Tags: android, numberpicker

Looks like NumberPicker on some versions of android return wrong result. 

For example I have:

Displayed values = { "3", "5", "10", "15", "30", "60" }

Real values = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5} // Set by android

If I choose Displayed value "15", I expect to get numberPicker.getValue() = 3. But on some devices I get 15 (Acer Liquid E2 Duo (rooted), Android 4.2.2).

Is there any way to get index of selected value? Or get list of real values for Number Picker?

```
String[]     stringTimerInterval    = { "3", "5", "10", "15", "30", "60" }
npTimer.setDescendantFocusability(NumberPicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
npTimer.setMaxValue(5);
npTimer.setMinValue(0);
npTimer.setValue(interval);
npTimer.setDisplayedValues(stringTimerInterval);
npTimer.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
```

Comment: Please provide full code of initializing your `NumberPicker`.

Comment: Posted initializing code

Comment: Looks normal, maybe it's specific issue of device's firmware or `getValue()` could not return value greater then `5` or you change limits and value at other place of your code.

Comment: There are not other changes. And on all devices works fine. I  think the only solution hear is to hardcode this device and firmware case